# Can IntelliJ be made to look like notebook?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, packages, workbench

I am developing a package for my company, which has grown into multiple sub-packages. I have been using the notebook frontend for `.wl` files which is ok but I need to open many files and also I want the line-collapsing feature of Eclipse as seen in the [video](https://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?v=3143).

[image]

I like the bright background notebook-like syntax color in Wolfram Workbench. But the official [website](https://www.wolfram.com/workbench/) say it is "Workbench supports products based on Wolfram Language Versions 10, 11 and 12". I am using versions 13.3 and 14 on different systems. Will I still be able to use it?

I see IntelliJ IDE does support newer versions but I find the black background and non-standard coloring orange, blue etc (not similar to the official notebook like black for assigned and blue for unknown) distracting:

[image]

Is there an easier way to make IntelliJ look like the workbench/notebook with a bright white background and notebook like syntax coloring and font. Does the IntelliJ plugin has template or some default to do that?